# I can´t press the button in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After filling in a form, which is inside a frame that I have to access. Have a submit button, inside the same frame but I can't press the button.

This is the button (Calcular precio):
[screenshot of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjXNs.png)

I have tried pressing the button in and out of the frame. Outside the frame it says it can't find it and when it is inside it doesn't give errors, but it doesn't execute.

```
driver.get("https://www.asefasalud.es/")
time.sleep(2) 

#cerrar popUp:
driver.find_element_by_class_name("sj-close-popup").click() 

#form:
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='calcular-seguro-medico']"))
driver.find_element_by_id("inputDiafnac1").send_keys("02") 
driver.find_element_by_id("inputMesfnac1").send_keys("02")
driver.find_element_by_id("inputAnniofnac1").send_keys("1990") 
driver.find_element_by_id("cPostalBasico").send_keys("41011")

#button:
#time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='botonValidar']").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

I've also tried with ActionChains and using send_keys(Keys.ENTER) - send_keys("\n"), instead of click(). With ActionChains it works the same as without it. And with send_keys I get the following error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr8Hk.png)

I don't know what could be going on.

Comment: I tried your code block and I don't see a problem with that.

It worked straight without any error, even the one you mentioned

Comment: Don't use time.sleep to wait, instead use WebDriverWait. Use it like this
It will wait for 200 seconds or till the element is interactable

    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    waiting_time = 200 # 200 seconds
    WebDriverWait(driver, waiting_time).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

Comment: A screenshot of the page is fine, a screenshot of the HTML is not. We can't try locators, etc. on a screenshot where we can with the HTML as text. Also, copy/paste the text of the error into your question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @KumarShivamRay. When the code to press the button is inside the frame, it doesn't give an error, but it doesn't execute. I also used WebDriverWait, but with the same result.

Comment: @JeffC. Actually the error appears when I try other ways to get it to run. With that code no error appears, but in the firefox WebDriver it doesn't run.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'll try with the same

Comment: @KumarShivamRay. I'm using firefox WedDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using execute_script inside the frame:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_id("botonValidar"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `xpath` for the **botonValidar** to

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"botonValidar\"]/parent::div").click()
```

And your code works fine. Please mark as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I've tried it and with the id, but it still won't run.